# jQuery .find changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still learning jQuery so this may be a simple one. When a link is clicked I wish to change the text in a div which is a copy of another one on the page, I am deleting the copy and updating the text in the original. I have the parent id and pass the inner div, but the text does not change.

Thanks

```
            var idValues = $(this).parents(".listingContainer").attr('id');
            idValues = '#' + idValues
            $(this).parents(".listingContainer").remove();
            $(idValues).find("div.saveCompare").text('Compare removed')
```

In idValues is #001 which is correct.

Here is the div:

```
<div class="listingContainer grid_9 alpha omega" id="001">
                <a href="adContent.html" class="listContent">
                    <div class="listingWrapper">
                        <div class="grid_8 alpha omega">
                            <div class="listingContent">
                                <div class="imgHolder">
                                    <img width="100" height="75" src="imgs/cars/SearchThumb-10053319.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="descHolder">
                                    <div id="car"></div>
                                    <h3>Fancy Car</h3><div class="saveCompareShow">Compare Added</div>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ex duis maiorum commune, illud viderer suscipiantur eam an. Dolorum recteque qui in. Pro inani nulla tacimates ex, qu</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="goTo goTo_unfocus grid_1 alpha omega">
                            <div class="gotoWrapper">
                                Click to View
                                <div class="imgVeiw"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--End listingWrapper-->
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: if i am right, you are deleting the whole div and then trying to find an element inside that div how can code work if the div is already removed?

Comment: there are two copies of the div on the page, one under each tab. One tab is the full listings and the other is view latter. In view latter the user can remove the listing and the main listing will be updated to say save removed. So in short there is still a div on the page with the id. Thanks

Comment: and both of them has the same id?

Comment: you can not have two elements with same ID , ID must be unique , instead use a class

Comment: yes thanks, I am going to change to class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can not have numeric id's `001`

2.i can not find a class called `saveCompare`  , are you reffering to `saveCompareShow`

**NOTE**

`HTML` `ID` atttribute

> Specifies a unique id for the element. Naming rules: Must begin with a
>   letter A-Z or a-z Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9),
>   hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_") In HTML, all values are
>   case-insensitive

Comment: Yes you are about saveCompareShow, when the user clicks the div to save listing it changes to saveCompareShow. I did say it maybe simple. Thanks for spotting that. Wasted some time on that thinking it was my jQuery skills. Now works. Thanks